# One corollary to Kolchin-Mal'cev's theorem.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In this following paper, I understood how to use the theorem, but I fail to see how I can show that $G$ is a linear group to be able to use the theorem.

Given that each factor is abelian, how do we show that the group is linear?

[image]

Comment: Abelian groups are definitely not $\mathbb{Q}$-vectorspaces in general.

Comment: Your revised statement is still not correct.

Comment: is it correct that it can be embedded in  $\mathbb{Q}$-vectorspaces?